# How to read every item in an Array using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i would like to know how to read every array item using `jQuery`.
I'm getting some `li` values, push them in an array and then sort them using a bubble sort function

```
function sortSizes(sizesArr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < sizesArr.length; i ++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < sizesArr.length; j ++) {
          ....
          ...
        }
    }
}
sortSizes(myArray)
```

all what i need then is to get every item in array and added to an `href` attribute

Comment: Seems like you should just use `$.each`

Comment: `$.each` is your friend

Comment: Seem like you should just use the native `forEach`

Comment: you can use `forEach` like  `array.forEach(function(value,index,arr){});`

Comment: But one thing while sorting you'll need to swap values, just stick to the `for` will be my advice! Plus the inner loop isn't event looping throgh the whole array!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through an array in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Why not using the native [**Array.prototype.sort**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) function?

Comment: Do you need to use what you have posted thus far? Or are you open to using alternate solutions? If so, like pretty much every other comment, `$.each` is a perfect solution.  Maybe edit your question to include a sample of an array and what you expect as a result/outcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***You can use `$.each` (just a sample example)-***

```js
var arr = [
   'one',
   'two',
   'three',
   'four',
   'five'
];
$.each(arr, function (index, value) {
 $('#mydiv').append(value+"<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "mydiv"></div>
```

***Or `forEach()`:-***

```js
var arr = [
   'one',
   'two',
   'three',
   'four',
   'five'
];
arr.forEach(function(value,index){
 $('#mydiv').append(value+"<br>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "mydiv"></div>
```